# Exact value of $\cos^2(\frac{\pi}{8})+\sin^2(\frac{15\pi}{8})?$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

I tried separating it into $\cos^2(\frac{\pi}{8})+\sin^2(\frac{\pi}{8}+\frac{14\pi}{8})?$ and using the angle sum identity but it didn't help.

Comment: $15\pi/8 = 2\pi - \pi/8$

Comment: Hint: $15\pi/8 = 2\pi-(\pi/8)$. What identities do you know for sin?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Notice that $\frac{15\pi}{8} = 2\pi - \frac{\pi}{8}$. So $\sin \frac{15\pi}{8} = -\sin \frac{\pi}{8}$. Your expression then reduces/evaluates down to:

$$\cos^2 \frac{\pi}{8} + \sin^2 \frac{\pi}{8} = 1$$

Answer (score 2):

Notice that for all $x$ we have $\sin\left(2\pi-x\right)=\sin(-x)=-\sin(x)$ due to $2\pi$-[periodicity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Periodic_function) of $\sin$ and the fact it is an [odd function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/OddFunction.html).

Applying, have
$$\sin\left(\frac{15\pi}{8}\right)^2=\left(\sin\left(2\pi-\frac{\pi}8\right)\right)^2=\left(\sin\left(-\frac{\pi}8\right)\right)^2=\sin\left(\frac{\pi}8\right)^2;$$

returning back to the original expression we get
$$\cos\left(\frac{\pi}8\right)^2+\sin\left(\frac{15\pi}8\right)^2=\cos\left(\frac{\pi}8\right)^2+\sin\left(\frac{\pi}8\right)^2,$$
which by [the fundamental trigonometric identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pythagorean_trigonometric_identity) $\sin(x)^2+\cos(x)^2=1$ easily gives
$$\therefore\cos\left(\frac{\pi}8\right)^2+\sin\left(\frac{15\pi}8\right)^2=\boxed{1}\,.$$

Answer (score 1):

Using $\cos2A=2\cos^2A-1=1-2\sin^2A$

$$2\cos^2\dfrac\pi8=1+\cos\dfrac\pi4$$

$$2\sin^2\dfrac{15\pi}4=1-\cos\dfrac{15\pi}4$$

Now $\cos\dfrac{15\pi}4=\cos\left(4\pi-\dfrac\pi4\right)=\cos\dfrac\pi4$